# Compare string with wildcard - ignoring case

Tags: bash

What I basically want to do is

```
if [[ $str == A* ]]; then 
# ...
```

But I want to ignore the case so both examples should be matched:

```
str=Abc
str=abc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options.

Match both manually:

```
if [[ $str == [aA]* ]]; then
```

Use `nocasematch`:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ $str == A* ]]; then
```

As Tom Fenech points out with bash 4+ (I believe) you can also use the new case modifying Parameter Expansions:

```
# For lower-casing
if [[ ${str,,} = a* ]]; then

# For upper-casing
if [[ ${str^^} = A* ]]; then
```

Comment: Option 3: `[[ ${str,,} = a* ]]`

Comment: I like the `nocasematch` in this case. Thanks for your detailed answer, works like a charm.

Comment: `nocasematch` affects other shell operations as well so it is the least localized option here, just keep that in mind.